# I want to copy content of one docx to another with all the formats intact.(Images, bullets and numbering etc)

Tags: apache, docx

This is the current situation of the code. I need to import all the images in the correct format and location. And also need the bullets and numbering to be intact. 
The main motive is to translate the document from english to french, but with all the formats intact.

```
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("d:\\Profiles\\nishgupta\\Desktop\\Test1.docx"); 
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is);

        List<XWPFParagraph> paras = doc.getParagraphs();             

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        XWPFDocument newdoc = new XWPFDocument();                                     
        for (XWPFParagraph para : paras) {  

            if (!para.getParagraphText().isEmpty()) {       
                XWPFParagraph newpara = newdoc.createParagraph();
                copyAllRunsToAnotherParagraph(para, newpara);
            }
            else
            { 
                XWPFParagraph blankpara = newdoc.createParagraph();
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                XWPFRun blank = blankpara.createRun();                  
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("d:\\Profiles\\nishgupta\\Desktop\\Test2.docx"));
        newdoc.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } 

// Copy all runs from one paragraph to another, keeping the style unchanged
private static void copyAllRunsToAnotherParagraph(XWPFParagraph oldPar, XWPFParagraph newPar) {
    final int DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE = 10;

    for (XWPFRun run : oldPar.getRuns()) {  
        String textInRun = run.getText(0);
      if (textInRun == null || textInRun.isEmpty()) {
         continue;
     }    

        int fontSize = run.getFontSize();

        newPar.setAlignment(oldPar.getAlignment());
        XWPFRun newRun = newPar.createRun();

        // Copy text
        newRun.setText(textInRun);

        // Apply the same style
        newRun.setFontSize( ( fontSize == -1) ? DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE : run.getFontSize() );    
        newRun.setFontFamily( run.getFontFamily() );
        newRun.setBold( run.isBold() );
        newRun.setItalic( run.isItalic() );
        newRun.setColor( run.getColor() );
        newRun.setBold(run.isBold());
        newRun.setColor(run.getColor());
        newRun.setCapitalized(run.isCapitalized());
        newRun.setDoubleStrikethrough(run.isDoubleStrikeThrough());
        newRun.setEmbossed(run.isEmbossed());
        newRun.setItalic(run.isItalic());
        newRun.setImprinted(run.isImprinted());
        newRun.setKerning(run.getKerning());
        newRun.setShadow(run.isShadowed());
        newRun.setSmallCaps(run.isSmallCaps());
        newRun.setUnderline(run.getUnderline());
        newRun.setStrikeThrough(run.isStrikeThrough());         
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: I am on mostly linux-php side but can't you simply copy the file on Operating System? PS: i don't know if its possible on .net or on docx library etc. just mentioing

Comment: What problem are you having with the current code? You need to describe an actual problem that you are having rather than just want you want to do, accompanied with a bunch of code.